# Plot 2 data sets from the same file using gnuplot, without changing data.dat format

Tags: gnuplot

I am using the following data.dat file:

```
3 1387.0967741935483 1 
6 1639.8976592916093 1 
9 2134.0472946621827 1 
3 870.98734610443798 0 
6 994.90178561297367 0 
9 1034.89761876391273 0
```

I wish to plot this data on a linespoints graph using the 3rd column as the data set indicator. So all the rows with a `1` in the 3rd column will be part of 1 data set and all the rows with a `0` will be part of the 2nd.

I am aware this can be done by changing the format of the data file, but this isn't possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tell Gnuplot to look for a `1` in column `3` and then print, do the same but specify a `0` for the second data set.

```
plot "test.dat" u 1:2:3:(stringcolumn(3) eq '1' ? $3 : 1/0), \
"test.dat" u 1:2:3:(stringcolumn(3) eq '0' ? $3 : 1/0)
```

Comment: Don't know why this was accepted as the solution, because it cannot work.